# The meaning of this sentence « je ride, ride, je fais du rodéo »

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, france, définition

I know the meaning of the French verb "rider" is plisser or to practice skating activities but the meaning doesn't make any sense in this sentence « je ride, ride, je fais du rodéo » it's from *Rodéo song Eva & Kidaki* ... what is the meaning of the sentence ?

Comment: C'est du franglais, je cavale/je cours au départ, mais *ride* est surtout un terme de motards qui font des rodéos (en moto) dans les cités au grand dam des riverains. Ensuite l'expression induit un comportement marginal qui s'enorgueillit de cette forme de liberté qui empiète sur celle des autres.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question 

Comment: @Personne Intéressant. L'association de rodéo avec moto c'est complètement étranger pour moi, et je n'avais jamais rencontré _rodéo motorisé_ ou _urbain_ avant de regarder sur Wiktionnaire il y a 5 mins. La composition me faisait penser à  _vivre à 100 mille à l'heure_, se démener, avec une idée de dominance et d'être surelevé, cavale oui mais chevaucher, monter, triompher. Beaucoup d'anglais et d'argot.

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie … c'est vraiment la perception qui correspond à cette pulsion juvénile, qui n'est pas très éloignée de celle des années 70, un mélange de mai 68 et de Californie, un vent de liberté dans un contexte différent.